# Invalid token SELECT

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-10.0

Hi I am trying to get the content of bucket Id using content resolver in android Q I am getting this Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #7
Process: com.dev.newtermain, PID: 13048
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token SELECT
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:472)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1183)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1115)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1071)
```

My Selection query is

```
selection = "bucket_id = ?) UNION SELECT _data, date_added, 0 as isImage FROM video WHERE (bucket_id = ?";
uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
selectionArgs = new String[]{bucketIdString};
String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED
    };
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
```

Any idea how I can fix this query

Comment: show some code how do you use this `selection` variable, currently it isn't even properly formatted (some chunk data at start, lack of or too much brackets on the end)

Comment: Please check I have Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selection` parameter in `ContentResolver::query` does only support `WHERE` clauses (without the `WHERE` keyword). [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver)

Your approach is including the `UNION` clause in the `selection` which is invalid. If you need a union, you may have to do two separate queries and combine the two results yourself.

**EDIT**

For your specifc case the `selection` should be defined as follows

```
selection = "bucket_id = ?"
```

Comment: as you suggest I am making seprate call for video and image and merging there data and I have Changed My Projection to `String[] projection = new String[]{                 MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED         };` and My selection to `selection = "SELECT data, date_added WHERE bucket_id = ?"` but result is same

Answer (score 1):

check out this selection

```
"SELECT _data, date_added, 0 as isImage FROM video WHERE bucket_id = ?";
```

- removed `bucket_id = ?)` on start - this is just wrong, not proper format, doesn't fit to beginning of query...
- removed following `UNION` as there is no union two selectors at all, just simple query for single `video` table
- at the end removed unneeded opening bracket (`WHERE (bucket_id = ?` to `WHERE bucket_id = ?`)

but note that `query` is encapsulated and won't accept full single-string sqlite query, you have to split it for parts. variable `selection` would be `"bucket_id = ?"` for matching `selectionArgs`

also note that projection is a bit weird...

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED
};
```

first two values are using `MediaStore.Images` instead of `MediaStore.Video` and all three doesn't match params in `selection` `SELECT _data, date_added, 0 as isImage FROM` - I see two params and one probably not needed static value

edit: I've just noticed you are selecting by Images - `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` - but selection is pointing on video column... also I doubt that `bucket_id` column exists in `MediaStore` database, there is no such value in static declarations of columns... I would suggest you read a bit about sql and querying, because your snippet looks like every line is comming from another piece of code....

Comment: I have Changed My Projection to `String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED
        };` and My selection to `selection = "SELECT data, date_added WHERE bucket_id = ?"` but result is same